# send ical invitation on email using codeigniter email library

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, icalendar

i want to send calender invitation into email. i tried below code to send ical invitation but it is not working.

i am using codeigniter Email Libraray to send email.

Create ical request like below

```
$ical = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:" . md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)) . "@test.com
DTSTAMP:" . gmdate('Ymd').'T'. gmdate('His') . "Z
DTSTART:19970714T170000Z
DTEND:19970715T035959Z
SUMMARY:New event
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR";
```

And then i add this content to:

```
$this->email->set_header('Content-type', 'text/calendar');
$this->email->attach($ical);
```

But it is not working. which thing i missed or doing wrong please suggest me.

i am trying to get below result in email
[image]

Comment: did you validate your ical? you can do so with e.g. https://icalendar.org/validator.html and many others

Comment: i validate ical it correct.....after send ical download option is there but how can i show content which is i mention in my question (like above image)

Answer (score 0):

here is a snippet from my emails_model that sends calendar events:

```
/**
 * @param $event
 *
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function calendar_event($event)
{
  $this->load->library('email');
  if (empty($event->end_dt))
  {
    $event->end_dt = clone $event->start_dt;
    $event->end_dt->modify('+30 minutes');
  }
  $location        = $event->location ?? '';
  $organizer       = SITE_NAME;
  $organizer_email = Emails_dto::send_from;
  $cr              = "\n";

  /** @var DateTimeZone $tz */
  $tz      = $event->start_dt->getTimeZone();
  $dt      = new \DateTime (NULL, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
  $subject = html_entity_decode($event->subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
  $headers = 'From: ' . SITE_NAME . ' <' . Emails_dto::send_from . '>' . $cr;
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0{$cr}";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: text/calendar; method=REQUEST;{$cr}";
  $headers .= '        charset="UTF-8"' . $cr;
  $headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit' . $cr;

  $message    = 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR' . $cr;
  $message    .= 'PRODID:-//i3SoftWebsite//cal_events/NONSGML v1.0//EN' . $cr;
  $message    .= 'VERSION:2.0' . $cr;
  $message    .= 'CALSCALE:GREGORIAN' . $cr;
  $message    .= 'METHOD:REQUEST' . $cr;
  $message    .= 'BEGIN:VEVENT' . $cr;
  $message    .= 'UID:' . md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), TRUE)) . '@' . SITE_DOMAIN_NAME . $cr;
  $message    .= 'CREATED:' . $dt->format("Ymd\THis") . 'Z' . $cr;
  $message    .= 'DTSTAMP:' . gmdate('Ymd') . 'T' . gmdate('His') . 'Z' . $cr;
  $message    .= 'DTSTART;TZID=' . $tz->getName() . ':' . $event->start_dt->format("Ymd\THis") . $cr;
  $message    .= 'DTEND;TZID=' . $tz->getName() . ':' . $event->end_dt->format("Ymd\THis") . $cr;
  $message    .= "SUMMARY:{$subject}{$cr}";
  $message    .= "ORGANIZER;CN={$organizer}:mailto:{$organizer_email}{$cr}";
  $message    .= "LOCATION:{$location}{$cr}";
  $message    .= "SEQUENCE:0{$cr}";
  $message    .= 'DESCRIPTION:' . html_entity_decode($event->description, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . $cr;
  $recipients = [$event->email_to];
  if (empty($event->recipients) === FALSE
    && is_array($event->recipients))
  {
    foreach ($event->recipients as $recipient)
    {
      $message      .= 'ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=' . $recipient['name'] . ';X-NUM-GUESTS=0:MAILTO:' . $recipient['email'] . $cr;
      $recipients[] = $recipient['email'];

    }
  }
  $message .= 'END:VEVENT' . $cr;
  $message .= 'END:VCALENDAR' . $cr;
  // @codeCoverageIgnoreStart
  $email_status = ENVIRONMENT === 'production'
    ? (int)mail($event->email_to, $subject, $message, $headers)
    : 0;
  // @codeCoverageIgnoreEnd
  $email                 = new stdClass();
  $email->ema_created_dt = $dt->format(DATETIME_MYSQL);
  $email->ema_from       = $organizer_email;
  $email->ema_to         = implode(',', $recipients);
  $email->ema_subject    = $subject;
  $email->ema_body       = $message;
  $email->ema_status     = $email_status;
  $email->ema_body       = substr($headers . $message, 0, 1431655760); // trim this to longtext.
  $this->add($email);
}
```